# Filename maxlength

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form for file upload like this

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sometimes user upload files with 200 characters name.
Exist a way to limit filename maxlenghth?

Comment: You shouldn't care about filename size from the client side, just rename the uploaded file in the server side.

Comment: Definitely not from HTML/JavaScript (that I know of).

Comment: to be fair the limit on this could cause more trouble than you need, if a user has a file located in ie: d:\backup\jan\2013\pictures\holiday\somethingelse\foldername\cant\think\off\any\thing\else\image.jpg, if youre looking for a way to display just the filename of the selected upload, most browsers take care of this issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Code from Graham and check the filename length also with PHP

```
if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 200) { echo "filename to long"; exit; }
```

and you must added MAX_FILE_SIZE to you HTML-form otherwise PHP don't get the uploaded file

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="MaximumFilesizeInBytes">
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser will expose the base file name to JavaScript so this is technically possible, although as @VisioN mentioned above, I can't think why you'd care; just rename the file on the server to something else. If you absolutely need to prevent it, then give your  element an ID of `uploader` and then:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("uploader").onsubmit = function(){
    return document.getElementById("file").value.length < 200; 
};
</script>
```

Of course this will only work if JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should also validate it PHP side since someone could submit it directly to upload_file.php and bypass any HTML/JavaScript restrictions.