# Max length of uploaded file name

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have standard html form for upload files

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
...
```

What is maximum length of filename, which can be uploaded by user ?

P.S.

I'm saving file on server with modified name, but also need to keep original name, because I use original name at downloading that file.

Comment: a the question is for the length of the filename or the size of the file ? If it's for the length of filename in post you have a very large limit (approching MB)

Comment: I would check all the filename limits on all the possible operating system

Comment: @Inazo - question is for the length of the filename

Comment: What operating system you are using?

Comment: I can tell you that on Windows its about 32,000 characters for filename and path but only 255 chars for just the filename

Comment: possible duplication of this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844825/filename-maxlength

Comment: @afikri If you feel that it is a duplicate, you should "flag" it as one, rather than posting it as a comment. However, that isn't a very good one, IMHO.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - What if user is bad guy and tries to send hacked name (i.e. not real file name, but some very long fake name)

Comment: your question is getting more unclear, given that ^ also.

Comment: so, @Shujaat asked for which OS this is related to; windows? linux/unix, other? it's important to know which animal we're dealing with here.

Comment: Question's been closed with 2 duplicates; your answers are in there.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - user  uploads `a.jpg` but tries to send veeeery long value for html form `file` parameter. Is this scenario  impossible ?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: I don't save files with the name supplied by the user, I lie to them and make them think I saved it with that name :),  `$filename = "{$user_id}".hash_file('sha1', $tempFile);` and then I save their name in the DB and my name, show them their name. Solves all kinds of issues.

Comment: So, @RIKI you asked an incorrect question. Your question should be like "How to restrict length of file name?"

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - Yes, exactly, I'm just interested should I care about name length at upload? cos, I use original name at download, there is possible that user uploads file with 500 symbol but it will truncated automatically for example to 255 symbol, because my server have different config?

Comment: I wouldn't use their name on the filesystem at all, because you can have a lot off issues with things like spaces, symbols etc.  Then it's a matter of what you set the DB to, save it with your name, show them their name.

Comment: @Shujaat It does not matter what OS the OP is using. A sender could be on any OS

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am agree with you. But the length of filename and path belongs to the operating system.

Comment: So OP needs to know what is the MAX filename lenght on ALL Operating system so he knows the largest

Comment: @RIKI - once I get my site done, I'll write a blog post on it... Don't hold your breath though I am lazy when it comes to my site.  http://www.artisticphoenix.com/

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not belong to HTML or PHP. Its totally depend on your operating system.

In windows length of both path and filename should not exceed 260 characters. Otherwise it will give your error.

In the Windows API, the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters". The total path is, for all practical purposes, limited to 259 characters (allowing for the null-terminator)

In the case of windows, you can find out more details on the link given below...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file

Comment: Does that apply to all possible operating systems or just yours

Comment: I have edited my answer. The information i shared is valid for windows operating system.

Comment: What about all the others, any OS can be a client to a web site